# upload file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tring to upload a file with NodeJs here is my code.

```
app.post('/upload',urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

// The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
var sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

// Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
sampleFile.mv(__dirname + '/upload', function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);

    console.log('File uploaded!');
});});
```

The promblem is tha i get that error.

```
    /path_of_my_pc/node_modules/fileupload/lib/modules/file.js:23
  throw error
  ^
```

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/upload'
    at Error (native)

The file where the all the code is, have all permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is about 'fileupload' module which is not used in this code. So if you are sure about using it, give all needed permissions to this project. But as you can see [here](https://github.com/domharrington/fileupload) it's better to use for example 'busboy' for uploading files

Comment: I use the `express-fileupload` and i work very well.

Answer (score 0):

change permission
Ex#

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/yourSiteName
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```